# Draw a graph using braille characters

Tags: python

I hacked together a way to make a small graph using Braille unicode codepoints by abusing `unicodedata`:

```
def plot(timeline):
  ret = []
  for r1, r2 in zip(timeline[::2], timeline[1::2]):
    character_name = "BRAILLE PATTERN DOTS-"
    dots  = [x for x, y in zip("7321", range(r1))]
    dots += [x for x, y in zip("8654", range(r2))]
    character_name += "".join(sorted(dots))
    ret.append(unicodedata.lookup(character_name) if dots else " ")
  return "".join(ret)


>>> print plot([random.randrange(0,4) for _ in range(100)])
 ⣆⣆⣶⣤⢠⡀⣦⡆⢀⡄⣰⣠⣦⣆⣰⢰⢠⢰⣄⡄ ⣀⣦⡆⣄⣶⣤⣠⡆⣠⣦⣆  ⣰⣴⡄⣤⣀ ⡀⣄⡀⣦⣶⣰⣶⣄⣴
```

Barring low-hanging incremental improvements such as memoizing the call to `unicodedata.lookup`, what would be a more proper way to perform this lookup?

Comment: Probably the sanest thing is to use this kludge to precompute an array of array of characters once, then use that instead.

Comment: Can you explain what your concern is? What makes you think that this approach is improper?

Answer (score 4):

#### Why `zip`?

You have:

```
dots  = [x for x, y in zip("7321", range(r1))]
dots += [x for x, y in zip("8654", range(r2))]
```

You're never using the second part of that zip. So you're basically making lists for the two `range`s, making lists for the two `zip`s, making lists for the outcomes of those things, all to drop most of the information.

You can simplify that to just:

```
dots = '7321'[:r1] + '8654'[:r2]
```

#### character name

Try to avoid building up strings with `+=`. Instead just use `format`:

```
character_name = "BRAILLE PATTERN DOTS-{}".format(join(sorted(dots)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused by your list comprehensions:

```
dots  = [x for x, y in zip("7321", range(r1))]
```

What's the significance of `"7231"`? It would benefit from being a named constant, clarifying what it is.

Likewise, using `x` means I can't inferr anything from that name. `r1` and `r2` are also meaningless. If you named these differently, then I might be able to follow what's happening even without knowing that this is for creating braile characters. Even if their significance is semi-random, you should note that!

Also, you don't seem to use `y`. If that's the case, it's more pythonic to use an underscore instead of a `y`, to make it clear that you don't intend to use that value for anything.

If I'm reading this right, you're just using `range(r1)` with `zip` to affect how many characters out of `"7231"`, which is clever and effective but terribly unclear. A comment would clear up confusion here immensely and make it a lot easier to follow.

Comment: Braille characters in Unicode are named after the dots they have, and the numbering is, left to right, top to bottom, 1 4 2 5 3 6 7 8. The first three rows are numbered top to bottom, the fourth row was added later and thus got the next two available digits. As a result I use those strings to store the digits corresponding to dots in each column. That's the significance of `7321`.

Comment: I honestly was hoping in an approach that could get me those Unicode codepoints without having to build their name and look it up from a huge table of irrelevant things.